# How .htacces settings file, to disallow robots.txt in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, htaccess

How .htacces settings file, to disallow robots.txt in magento ?

I have used the following script

```
<Files ~ "\.(tpl|txt)$">
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
  SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Googlebot" goodbot
  Allow from env=goodbot
</Files>
```

but I still visible robots.txt if typed domain.com/robots.txt on my browser

I'am Use OS Server Debian and
Web Server Nginx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line to your .**htacces**

```
Disallow: robots.txt
```

Comment: I had to restart the server nginx but not run.

Answer (score 0):

on your `/etc/nginx/sites-available/your-vhost-file.conf`

Use below code:

```
server {
    #Your other nginx config lines.....
    #add this inside server {}
    location /robots.txt {
        if ($http_user_agent !~* (Googlebot) ) {
            return 403;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to restart the server nginx but not working

Comment: try my updated answer

Comment: Whye [FAIL] Starting nginx: nginx failed! ?

Comment: You should add this to your `server {   }` of the nginx vhost config